# Copying specific objects(according to given condition) from array of objects into an another array in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, controllers

I want to create a new array of objects from an existing array of objects , such that new array will have only have those objects which matches the condition defined in if statement. Below is the code snippet which i am attempting

Requirement is that when key.status=='completed' condition gets hit ,only those object which have status : 'completed' in orders array will get copied to temp array .But because of using angular.copy whole copy of objects is getting copied in temp array .
 .

--------html-----

```
<body ng-app ="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController">    
    <div ng-repeat="order in temp">

    {{order.id}} -- {{order.status}} -- {{order.name}}

    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

-------xxxx------

-------JS----------

```
<script>


  var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

  myModule.controller('myController',  function($scope) {

    $scope.orders = [ 
      {id: '101' , status : 'completed' , name: 'Jacopo' } ,
      {id: '102' , status : 'Rejected' , name: 'Dan' } ,
      {id: '103' , status : 'created' , name: 'Erick' } 
    ] ;

    $scope.temp = [ ] ;

    angular.forEach($scope.orders , function(key,value){ 
      if(key.status == 'completed') {
      angular.copy($scope.orders,$scope.temp)
      }

    } );

  } ) ;

</script>
```

------xxx--------

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
$scope.temp = $scope.orders.filter(function(o){return o.key === 'completed'});
```